# Transactionally switch two files?

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

I have a.tmp and b.tmp. I like to rename a to b and b to a however a.tmp must ALWAYS exist. Is it possible to do renames transactionally?

I'm using C# on windows. However i can use cmd/shellexecute to use other stuff built into windows

Comment: `a.tmp must ALWAYS exist` - why?

Comment: @KonradMorawski because i'll have to rewrite and spend lots of time debugging if it doesnt :x

Answer (score 2):

Use `File.OpenWrite` and write the contents of `b.tmp` into `a.tmp`. It will overwrite the contents of `a.tmp` without ever removing it from the folder.

Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Vista or higher and use NTFS, you could also have a look at a TxF wrapper like [Transactional NTFS](http://txfnet.codeplex.com/). It uses the NTFS transactions based on the Kernel Transaction Manager, and supposedly [integrates](http://txfnet.codeplex.com/documentation) with `TransactionScope` nicely, so you could also use it with database and over more than just one computer, if required.

Yes, this could be total overkill for your use-case, but I just wanted to drop this bit of info here, since you expressively asked about transactional file system operations.

Comment: +1. I ended up going with a different solution then these two answers. Its very simple. I'll post my answer in an hour or two

Answer (score 0):

Copy the contents of a.tmp to c.tmp, use the console move /Y via `cmd /c move /y thisfile thatfile` then rename c.tmp to b.tmp